# How to password protect a mod rewritten directory?

Tags: .htaccess

I rewrote a file to a directory in .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^folder1/(\/|)$  index.php?a=folder1 [NC,QSA]
```

How do I password-protect specifically this "folder1" only? So that when users go to mysite.com/folder1/ they get asked for a username & password to access it.

Comment: See this http://www.digitalfaq.com/forum/web-tech/2493-how-password-protect.html

Answer (score 0):

You can have your .htaccess like this:

```
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI ^/folder1(/.*)?$ SECURED

AuthType Basic
AuthName "Password Protected Folder1"
AuthUserFile /full/path/to/.htpasswd
Require valid-user

Satisfy    any
Order      Allow,Deny
Allow from all
Deny from env=SECURED

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^folder1/(/|)$  index.php?a=folder1 [NC,QSA,L]
```